# I deleted 'www-data' user, how can I rebuild a same one?

Tags: unix, nginx, permissions

I edited my `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` file without backups and found the user `www-data` I thought it is useless, then deleted it from these two files.

When I tried to start my Nginx service, I got a failure whose log shows nginx using the `www-data` user to produce workers!

Was the user created by Nginx when I installed it or It was there since the big bang (I mean is it inherent user)?

Should I recreate the user and give some permissions to it (although I have no idea what permissions it needs), or just reinstall Nginx?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What OS are you using? On most linux user www-data is by default available with UID/GUID 33. In file /etc/passwd in Ubuntu and Debian you shoud have:

```
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

and in file /etc/group:

```
www-data:x:33:
```

Adding this two entries should be enough.

But of course you can use nginx as another user, just edit nginx.conf file. This is usefull sometimes when you have nginx for just for one website.